# How do I change the name of an imported library?

Tags: python, import, jython

I am using jython with a third party application. The third party application has some builtin libraries `foo`. To do some (unit) testing we want to run some code outside of the application. Since `foo` is bound to the application we decided to write our own mock implementation.

However there is one issue, we implemented our mock class in python while their class is in java. Thus to use their code one would do `import foo` and foo is the mock **class** afterwards. However if we import the python module like this we get the **module** attached to the name, thus one has to write `foo.foo` to get to the class.

For convenience reason we would love to be able to write `from ourlib.thirdparty import foo` to bind `foo` to the `foo`-**class**. However we would like to avoid to import all the classes in `ourlib.thirdparty` directly, since the loading time for each file takes quite a while.

Is there any way to this in python? ( I did not get far with Import hooks I tried simply returning the class from `load_module` or overwriting what I write to `sys.modules` (I think both approaches are ugly, particularly the later))

**edit**:

ok: here is what the files in ourlib.thirdparty look like simplified(without magic):

foo.py:

```
try:
    import foo
except ImportError:
    class foo
        ....
```

*Actually* they look like this:

foo.py:

```
class foo
    ....

__init__.py in ourlib.thirdparty
import sys
import os.path
import imp
#TODO: 3.0 importlib.util abstract base classes could greatly simplify this code or make it prettier.

class Importer(object):
    def __init__(self, path_entry):
        if not path_entry.startswith(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'thirdparty')):
            raise ImportError('Custom importer only for thirdparty objects')

        self._importTuples = {}

    def find_module(self, fullname):
        module = fullname.rpartition('.')[2]

        try:
            if fullname not in self._importTuples:
                fileObj, self._importTuples[fullname] = imp.find_module(module)

                if isinstance(fileObj, file):
                    fileObj.close()
        except:
            print 'backup'
            path = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'thirdparty'), module+'.py')
            if not os.path.isfile(path):
                return None
                raise ImportError("Could not find dummy class for %s (%s)\n(searched:%s)" % (module, fullname, path))

            self._importTuples[fullname] = path, ('.py', 'r', imp.PY_SOURCE)

        return self

    def load_module(self, fullname):
        fp = None
        python = False

        print fullname

        if self._importTuples[fullname][1][2] in (imp.PY_SOURCE, imp.PY_COMPILED, imp.PY_FROZEN):
            fp = open( self._importTuples[fullname][0], self._importTuples[fullname][1][1])
            python = True

        try:
            imp.load_module(fullname, fp, *self._importTuples[fullname])
        finally:
            if python:
                module = fullname.rpartition('.')[2]
                #setattr(sys.modules[fullname], module, getattr(sys.modules[fullname], module))
                #sys.modules[fullname] = getattr(sys.modules[fullname], module)

                if isinstance(fp, file):
                    fp.close()

                return getattr(sys.modules[fullname], module)



sys.path_hooks.append(Importer)
```

Comment: `from ourlib.thirdparty import foo as foo` ?

Comment: What's `ourlib.thirdparty`?  Is that mock python code you wrote, or the java code?

Comment: Do you need the other classes from `ourlib.thirdparty`? Your third paragraph is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: @PierreGM Surely the `as foo` is redundant for `from ... import foo`? It's already in the namespace as `foo`.

Comment: @PierreGM: It would be `from ourlib.thirdparty.foo import foo` and we want to do `from ourlib.thirparty import foo`

Comment: @mgilson `ourlib.thirdparty` is supposed to be a package. If it were a module you would always import the whole thing. It is jython. Since we are not able to do as we want now it currently is a module with the downside that we always include all third partylibs/mock replacements (the job of the package is to load the thirdparty code if available otherwise our mockups). Sure we can pick what we bring into the namespace with the `from ourlib.thirdparty import foo, bar, zig, zag` but the initializationpenality for the seperate files remains. I feel this is going towards a curiosity ...(see below)

Comment: (continued) ... question, since the performance penalty is pretty low, especially since we moved some startup code into the first construction of any class instance (close to a singelton)

Answer (score 0):

As others have remarked, it is such a plain thing in Python that the `import` statement iself has a syntax for that:

`from foo import foo as original_foo`, for example - 
or even `import foo as module_foo`

Interesting to note is that the `import` statemente binds a name to the imported module or object ont he local context - however, the dictionary `sys.modules`  (on the moduels `sys of course), is a live reference to all imported modules, using their names as a key. This mechanism plays a key role in avoding that Python re-reads and re-executes and already imported module , when running (that is, if various of yoru modules or sub-modules import the same`foo` module, it is just read once -- the subsequent imports use the reference stored in sys.modules).

And -- besides the "import...as" syntax, modules in Python are just another object: you can assign any other name to them in run time.

So, the following code would also work perfectly for you:

```
import foo
original_foo = foo
class foo(Mock):
   ...
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I can't use mock since it comes with jython 3 as far as I know and not with (j)ython 2.5. To turn myeslef back to the root:I updated my question with the code currently in use to clarify slightly that I would find it great if I could do this renaming automatically, why write `from ourlib.thirdpartylib.foo import foo` when one can write `from ourlib.thirdpartylib import foo` and even better `import foo`.The last is the best, then you can use  the code without our mock library(third party lib req then). All that would be required is to change the find method in the import hook.

Comment: ...But the proper renaming is a prerequisite.