# No module name 'sklearn.ensemble.forest'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, virtualenv

I am using this code to detect `face_spoofing`

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
import joblib
from face_detector import get_face_detector, find_faces

def calc_hist(img):
    """
    To calculate histogram of an RGB image

    Parameters
    ----------
    img : Array of uint8
        Image whose histogram is to be calculated

    Returns
    -------
    histogram : np.array
        The required histogram

    """
    histogram = [0] * 3
    for j in range(3):
        histr = cv2.calcHist([img], [j], None, [256], [0, 256])
        histr *= 255.0 / histr.max()
        histogram[j] = histr
    return np.array(histogram)

face_model = get_face_detector()
clf = joblib.load(0)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("videos/face_spoofing.mp4")

sample_number = 1
count = 0
measures = np.zeros(sample_number, dtype=np.float)

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    faces = find_faces(img, face_model)

    measures[count%sample_number]=0
    height, width = img.shape[:2]
    for x, y, x1, y1 in faces:
        
        roi = img[y:y1, x:x1]
        point = (0,0)
        
        img_ycrcb = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)
        img_luv = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LUV)

        ycrcb_hist = calc_hist(img_ycrcb)
        luv_hist = calc_hist(img_luv)

        feature_vector = np.append(ycrcb_hist.ravel(), luv_hist.ravel())
        feature_vector = feature_vector.reshape(1, len(feature_vector))

        prediction = clf.predict_proba(feature_vector)
        prob = prediction[0][1]

        measures[count % sample_number] = prob

        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x1, y1), (255, 0, 0), 2)

        point = (x, y-5)

        # print (measures, np.mean(measures))
        if 0 not in measures:
            text = "True"
            if np.mean(measures) >= 0.7:
                text = "False"
                font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
                cv2.putText(img=img, text=text, org=point, fontFace=font, fontScale=0.9, color=(0, 0, 255),
                            thickness=2, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
            else:
                font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
                cv2.putText(img=img, text=text, org=point, fontFace=font, fontScale=0.9,
                            color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=2, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
        
    count+=1
    cv2.imshow('img_rgb', img)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am using the version `0.24.0` for `scikit` and I am on Python 3.8 to use `tensorflow`

But I get the error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/heman/PycharmProjects/ProctorAI/face_spoofing.py", line 29, in <module>
>     clf = joblib.load('models/face_spoofing.pkl')
>   File "C:\Users\heman\PycharmProjects\ProctorAI\venv\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 585, in load
>     obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
>   File "C:\Users\heman\PycharmProjects\ProctorAI\venv\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 504, in _unpickle
>     obj = unpickler.load()
>   File "C:\Users\heman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\pickle.py", line 1212, in load
>     dispatch[key[0]](self)
>   File "C:\Users\heman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\pickle.py", line 1528, in load_global
>     klass = self.find_class(module, name)
>   File "C:\Users\heman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\pickle.py", line 1579, in find_class
>     __import__(module, level=0)
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.ensemble.forest'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1
> ```

I think I need to use the previous version of `scikit` (`0.19.1`) but I get the error: C++ build tools required. I don't know how to install these tools as I am in a virtual environment, they are already installed in my laptop.

Comment: This `sklearn.ensemble.forest` does not come from scikit-learn API as the standard is `sklearn.lowercase.UpperCase`. Check the source and see where that import come. I went all back to scikit-learn 0.16 and could not find it.

Comment: The library joblib is using it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`sklearn.ensemble.forest` was renamed to `sklearn.ensemble._forest` [in 437ca05 on Oct 16, 2019](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/437ca0553ce8d97571cecc3f4df8493e5cf959c5). You need to install an older `sklearn`. Try version 0.21.3 released on Jul 30, 2019:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn==0.21.3
```

Please be warned that the authors provided wheels up to Python 3.7. For 3.8 or 3.9 you will need to [compile from sources](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html#install-bleeding-edge).

Comment: I got it in scikit 0.23.0. I used the joblib present in the package as it was there in this version. You can do from scikit.externals import joblib and use it instead of externally using joblib

Comment: @SiddharthAgrawal I wasn't able to downgrade, so how did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

The answer above is correct,
`sklearn.ensemble.forest` is renamed to `sklearn.ensemble._forest`

This problem persist with more libraries that depend on sklearn, therefore I want to provide an additional solution that universally for most of these packages.

In your case your library is called `face_detector`, but you can replace it with any library name when you encounter this issue with versioning of scikit-learn (as well as with other libraries).

1. Locate the directory of the library:

   ```
   import face_detector
   print(face_detector.\_\_file__)
   ```
2. Open the file in any text editor, in your case the name of the library file would be `face_detector.py`
3. Out-comment the old import and replace with the new import.

   Comment out the import for the old versions of sklearn and add the new import statement

   ```
   # from sklearn.ensemble.forest import ForestClassifier, ForestRegressor
   from sklearn.ensemble._forest import ForestClassifier, ForestRegressor
   ```
4. Safe and enjoy, you just fixed a dependency issue!
   This solution will work for most libraries and is even less work than installing a different version of sklearn. In case it does not work, you can still install and older version as suggested in the other answer.

Note: This solution can be easily modified to trace and fix dependency issues for other library dependencies than sklearn. As long as the function itself did not change in input and output parameters, fixing renaming issues is an easy way to fix broken dependencies.

Comment: Is there a way, rather than changing code, to tell python to reinterpret a line with another? Basically, every time there is sklearn.ensemble.forest it should be reinterpreted as sklearn.ensemble._forest. That way, if there are many instances, they would be taken all cared for at once.

Comment: @user 
According to this post it is possible, I have not verified it though. See:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352626/how-do-i-change-the-name-of-an-imported-library#12353194

Answer (score 0):

maybe your model is too old. use:

```
pip install scikit-learn==0.22
```

to install the old version of sklearn.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Answering resolved questions is fine as long as you're providing new insight and not repeating something that was already established, which is the case here. The solution in the accepted answer has already established that installing an older version was needed.