# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.ensemble.forest'

Tags: python, error-handling, pickle, modulenotfounderror

I built a classifier `classifier_new.pkl` using

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
```

I pickled this calssifier and then tried to use it for a web application.

```
import pickle

pickle_in=open('classifier_new.pkl','rb')
```

After executing this code I got this error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.ensemble.forest'
```

What should I do instead or what could I examine in order to make it running?

I also searched for similar questions/answers for this problem and saw this solution: [No module name 'sklearn.forest.ensemble'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65758102/no-module-name-sklearn-forest-ensemble) but it did not work in my case...

Comment: You probably pickled it using an earlier version of scikit-learn. You need to use the same version to unpickle it.