# MondrianForestClassifier object has no attribute partial_fit

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

As per the skikit-garden [documentation](https://scikit-garden.github.io/api/#skgardenmondrianmondrianforestclassifier), `MondrianForestClassifier` includes a  `partial_fit` method:

`MondrianForestClassifier.partial_fit(X, y, classes=None)`

In google colab, I did the following,

```
!pip install scikit-garden
from skgarden import MondrianForestClassifier
mfc = MondrianForestClassifier()
for i in range(10):
    subset = slice(round(4596729*i),round(4596729*(i+1)))
    mfc.partial_fit(X_set[subset], y_set[subset], classes=np.unique(y_data))
```

while running the above cell, I get the following error,

```
AttributeError: 'MondrianForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'partial_fit'
```

Also there was no method 'partial_fit' found while running `dir(mfc)` in a cell.

So i tried installing scikit-garden in my laptop (locally).

Installing through 'pip' or 'conda', i get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.ensemble.forest'
```

In google colab, I think `fit` is working; but i need `partial_fit` to run out-of-core training process.

is there a way to fix this in google colab?

Answer (score 1):

The error that you encountered is due to `scikit-garden` not being compatible with recent versions of `scikit-learn`. As suggested in this post, try to use version 0.21.3 ([No module name 'sklearn.ensemble.forest'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65758102/no-module-name-sklearn-ensemble-forest)).

The development of the `scikit-garden` package seems to have ended, unfortunately (https://github.com/scikit-garden/scikit-garden/issues/104), so do not expect a fix for this in the future.