# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.ensemble.iforest'

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror, shap

I use isolation forest model:

```
model =  IsolationForest()
```

But when I try

```
explainerModel = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
```

I got ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.ensemble.iforest'

How to solve this? I use anaconda. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No module name 'sklearn.forest.ensemble'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65758102/no-module-name-sklearn-forest-ensemble)

Answer (score 0):

You generally get a ModuleNotFoundError when that module/dependency is not locally installed in your pc/laptop. try installing the sklearn module with command prompy using `pip install sklearn` or using conda terminal `conda install sklearn`.